# Listview Scrolling changes Button Visibility?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am having a listview in my App. Each row has an button. I'm hiding the button for some rows with `setVisibility`. But the buttons visibility changes after scrolling the list. How can i stop this change ?

I already saw a question with the checkbox with Listview. But i don't know how to implement it for the buttons. So please guide me!

**ADAPTER**

```
public class published_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context con;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> class_list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title,description,class_section,date;
        ImageButton download;
        Button viewasgn;
    }

    public published_adapter(Context co, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list1) {
        class_list = list1;
        con = co;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return class_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return class_list.get(arg0).get("class_name");
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View row = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null)
        {
            row = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.assignment_adapter_layout, arg2, false);

            // initialize the elements
            holder.download = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.download);
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.class_section = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.class_section);
            holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.viewasgn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.attend);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        String type = class_list.get(arg0).get("ASSIGNMENT_TYPE");


        if (class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION").equals("0")) {
            Log.e("TITLE", class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION"));
        }
        else{
            Log.e("TITLE", class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION"));
            holder.viewasgn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.viewasgn.setText("VIEW");
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you hiding the buttons, there is no code for that which you posted?

Comment: We're supposed to assume that you're hiding the button in your assignment_adapter_layout.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
     if (class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION").equals("0")) {
            Log.e("TITLE", class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION"));
            holder.viewasgn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewasgn.setText("");
        }
        else{
            Log.e("TITLE", class_list.get(arg0).get("TOTAL_SUBMISSION"));
            holder.viewasgn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.viewasgn.setText("VIEW");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add the `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` like @Solhail suggested or hide those buttons by default in your assignment_adapter_layout.xml by adding `android:visibility="invisible"` in your Button's properties, and don't change a thing in your current adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case Views will be recreated when listView is scroll.
To prevent this, you should not use ViewHolder.

You need to user Adapter like this: 
(Only if you have not a lot elements)

```
public class SampleAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private Activity activity;

public SampleAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, Activity activity) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_element, parent, false);

    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);

    textViewTitle.setText(arrayList.get(position));


    return view;
} }
```